# Best practices to manage hardware variants in Firmware develpment

Tags: firmware, development, development-tools

As a product is developed, new hardware versions (variants) emerge. Sometimes, different hardware versions may include different types of ICs, and even new functionalities that are not included in previous hardware versions.

There are various ways of recognizing the hardware version, for example, detecting the value of a resistor by means of an RC network or by means of a resistor bridge.

Wirth respect the firmware, two options come to my mind in order to handle hardware variants:

- Compile static versions for each variant (for this it is sufficient to define changes in the firmware with #defines and conditions depending on the hardware version). This has a number of disadvantages, such as having to compile the different versions, one for each variant, distributing one version for each variant when there is an update etc.
- Have the same firmware working for all variants. This, in my view, is the best way for firmware development, since there is only one version, all boards are programmed with the same firmware, and only one update has to be served.

The optimal way to manage it is the second one, but what is the best way to implement it in the code without recurring to spaghetti code? (C or C++)

Comment: It is an interesting question, but is IMO one about software modularity. You can find examples for both approaches in the industry.

Comment: Seems a better question for SE: see e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156836/release-management-versions-control

Comment: @TimWilliams: Not necessarily, since the OP is concerned with hardware/firmware. I think, the conflict with your suggested reference is the very reason for the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question touches on a classic difference between high-level software and low-level hardware development. Hardware resources and memory to accommodate the firmware are much more limited as disk space when it comes to (bloated) applications on computers and handheld devices.

Being able to use a single firmware image across several design generations means that any future firmware may never grow beyond the memory that was available for the first generation. Hence, you would have to charge your customers excessively for the early generations to have enough memory to accommodate future firmware revisions that will not add value for the customer, since they are stuck with the old hardware (as detected by the R/RC network). How do you justify the additional cost to a customer?

My guess It will be easier to communicate and sell a modular design with custom firmware, i.e. a customer upgrades part of their system including the firmware. A classical example is a desktop computer: you can upgrade CPU, RAM, GPU, etc and continue operating the remaining hardware.

That said, it will be worthwhile to invest into a proper version/variant management. This is where state of the art tools of software development come in handy. Combine a generic code based on standardized libraries to avoid spaghetti code, and use automated processes to distill the variant's firmware as an tailored subset. This way, you efficiently handle bugfixes that affect all variants, as well as selected features that are only relevant for specific firmware variants.